# Pseudo code flow chart with numerical values

Tags: algorithm

[If ‘n’ is 6, what will be the final value of b?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oykOh.png)

I am struggling to make sense of this Algorithm . Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write down the values and step through the flowchart.

```
Initial:  n=6, a=0; b=1

is a < n?  Yes.
Display a (0)
a = b (1)
b = a+b = 1+1 = 2;

state n=6, a=1, b=2

is a < n?  Yes.
Display a (1)
a = b (2)
b = a+b = 2+2 = 4;

state n=6, a=2, b=4

is a < n? ...

continue until a is not < n
```